# Preloading local fonts using Tailwind CSS

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

How can I preload my fonts using Tailwind CSS? Perhaps in the `tailwind.config.js` file?

I'd like to preload fonts before UI rendering.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.